# How we determine type of filter with pole(s), zero(s)?

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, lowpass-filter, laplace-transform, poles-zeros

Let's say we have this Laplace transform:

$$H_{1}(s)=\frac{1}{(s+1)(s+3)}\;, \; \Re{e} (s)>-1 $$

So, we know that there is a poles at $s=-1$ and $s=-3$.

With these informations, we found that to be a low-pass filter in class. How? How do we sketch the frequency response? What are the conditions to determine filter types when we only know pole(s) and zero(s)?

Answer (score 4):

The frequency response of such a transfer function is given by letting $s=j\omega$:

$$
H(\omega) = H(s)\Big|_{s=j\omega} = \frac{1}{(j\omega+1)(j\omega+3)} = \frac{1}{(3-\omega^2)+4j\omega}
$$

Rough estimation of the filter type:

$$
H(0) = \frac{1}{3}, \ \ \ H(\infty) \to 0
$$

and we know it's a lowpass filter. Also further maths can be done

$$
|H(\omega)|^2 = \left|\frac{1}{(3-\omega^2)+4j\omega}\right|^2 = \frac{1}{(3-\omega^2)^2+(4\omega)^2}=\frac{1}{\omega^4+10\omega^2+9}
$$

The squared magnitude response is illustrated as follows

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Supplemental answers. ZRHan has worked out the math already. Here is just a different way to plot it so you can really see the lowpass character.

[image]

The graphical interpretation can be derived by looking at very high and very low frequencies.

For $\omega \ll 1$ we assume $ ( 1 + j\omega) \approx 1$ and the transfer function becomes

$$H(\omega) \approx \frac{1}{(1)\cdot (3)} = \frac{1}{3}$$

so it's constant horizontal line.

For $\omega \gg 3$ we assume $ ( 3 + j\omega) \approx j\omega$ and the transfer function becomes

$$H(\omega) \approx \frac{1}{(j\omega)\cdot (j\omega)} = -\frac{1}{\omega^2}$$

which (on a log/log scale) is a falling line with a slope of -40dB per decade.

The 3dB point is in the vicinity of the poles, around $\omega_c \approx 0.91$.

If the poles were further apart you would actually see another line with a slope of -20dB per decade between the poles. But in this case the poles are too close together.